# Html5 Video and Flash Approach

Tags: flash, html, h.264, ogg, webm

Looking into HTML5 video tag, and researching which browsers support which video file types, and my initial thought is things just got harder than just using flash.

I am wondering if there is some skeleton code (combined with development approach for videos) that someone has figured out to do the following:

1. If flash is available, use it
2. If not, try html5 video ogg format
3. If that doesn't work, try html5 video h.264 format
4. If that doesn't work, try html5 video webM format

Based on what I am seeing, am I correct in thinking that now, in order to accommodate all users on all browsers, a video needs to be published in 4 formats? If so, this HTML5 video thing is an epic fail!

Anyway, any ideas, processes, links to libraries, etc are appreciated.

Thanks -

Comment: +1 for epic fail. Until the video patent mess is sorted out, it's a big PITA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that hard. You can give multiple sources (in multiple formats) for a single `<video>` tag.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="pr6.mp4"  type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
  <source src="pr6.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"'>
</video>
```

Also the better choice is to search for *native html5 video* first, then fallback to flash.

The two fromats you need are WebM (royaltiy free, supported by alternative briwsers Mozilla, Opera, Chrome and others) and H.264 for the big ones (IE and Safari). Your fallback option (flash) is also able to play H.264.

I suggest reading [this guide](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) if you haven't already.

**Edit:**

If you're looking for the lowest common demoninator then it's surely **hinted H.264 over HTTP**. Flash can play it without a media server and it's the only format iOS supports anyway, so you are OK for one single format for the time being.

But even with this single format you can support HTML5-bsed playback on the two factory teams (Safari and IE). I know the video tag is kinda new but they build on solid foundations in the OS's. Even at this state they are a better option than Flash.

So the real dilemma after all is ith the alternative browsers. You can use two formats instead of one (to throw in WebM) or you only stay with H.264 and use Flash on non-h264 browsers.

This is rather a question of personal preference (and the cost of double storage). But storage is generally free these days, bandwidth is the real cost factor anyway.

Comment: Why is it better to search for HTML5 first? Isn't Flash more widely supported currently? Or am I missing something or some benefit?

Comment: @OneNerd If only one or the other is present the choice is obvious. But when both are possible you want to prefer the native playback (HTML5), because it is safer (free from possible flash-crases) and requires far less CPU power (which translates to battery power too).

Comment: I see your point, but based on current state of affairs, wouldn't Flash First > HTML5 Video mean I could turn having to publish the video 3 times (formats) into just 2 (am thinking every browser under the sun except iPad/iPhone supports flash, so flash first, then use HTML5 Video format that iOS supports as failover). Is that viable, or am I missing something? Thanks -

Comment: @OneNerd It came out long enough, so I replied in an edit. In short: yep, you're right :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)? It might save you some time.