# viewing video on my webpage

Tags: video, media-player, html, embedding, semantic-markup

I have a link to an .mp4 video file that i must embed in my webpage.  I've googled and not very successful.  I've checked [here](http://websitehelpers.com/video/) and and [w3c here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_videos.asp).  But i'm having trouble figuring this out.  With both it seems i have to use two file formats for (mp4 and ogv).  I'm not sure that I can use a absolute URL either (?).  I want to see the video player controls (like youtube),but I am not using a youtube file.  Does anyone know the markup properties/elements needed to do something like this?  Thanks.

Comment: check also here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833496/html5-video-and-flash-approach

Comment: Thanks, yms. i'll check it out

Comment: That post has a dead link and i don't understand how to use jwplayer. I'll re-read the docs. I'm also reading [link](http://oembed.com/).  i thought i could just get the semantic code needed for displaying a video in a webpage.  If I need all formats for the various browsers, that's fine.  All I have is a link to a .mp4 video that once clicked, opens up in Chrome and starts to play full screen.  I can't use just that, I can't customize it (size, UI elements, etc.) to fit in the space of my webpage.  I guess this must be tough to do since there is only one response to my question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I've selected to use the brightcove player.  The UI is very easy to use and there is alot of documentation and step-by-step instructions.  After the videos are uploaded in a playlist (or individually) and assigned to a player, I can get the code through in Publisher mode.  I copy and paste the code into my webpage and it works.